# Huawei EC315 3G Dongle is not working in Ubundu

Tags: network-manager, usb-modem, arm, usb-modeswitch

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. I have an Ubuntu running board for Embedded development. I'm trying to configure Huawei EC315 modem for network connectivity.

The output of `lsusb` is the below:

```
root@texe_hub:~# lsusb

lsusb: cannot open "/usr/share/usb.ids", No such file or directoryBus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:14db

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
```

I'm successfully able to switch the device from Mass storage to Modem using the below command:

```
root@texe_hub:/etc/udev/rules.d# usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1f01 -J

Look for default devices ...

product ID matched

Found devices in default mode (1)

Access device 003 on bus 001

Current configuration number is 1

Use interface number 0

Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)


USB description data (for identification)
Manufacturer: Huawei Technologies
Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Serial No.: not provided

Using standard Huawei switching message

Looking for active driver ...

OK, driver detached

Set up interface 0

Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...

Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...

OK, message successfully sent

Reset response endpoint 0x81

Reset message endpoint 0x01
```

-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!

After that when I try to load the driver using `modprobe`, I'm getting the below error.

```
root@texe_hub:~# modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x14db

[ 312.839711] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial

[ 312.857796] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic

[ 312.877136] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic

[ 312.883334] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: Generic device with no bulk out, not allowed.

[ 312.904695] usbserial_generic: probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -5

[ 312.911203] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.

[ 312.934684] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.

[ 312.954987] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: generic converter detected

[ 312.979489] usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

How to fix this issue? Please guide on what I can do to get it working.

Comment: I guess this modem works on plug & play. It should be automatically connected. `lsusb` output shows `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:14db` Here your device is already converted into  modem. So it should be connected. If it wasn't converted into modem then output would be `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:1f01`. Dongle has its default IP like 192.168.X.Y written on it. In browser you can modify setting with this IP,  you can check there if it is not connected.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Initially, it was detected as 12d1:1f01. After the USBMODESWITCH only, it got changed to 12d1:14db. It's an Embedded board. So I have tried to use WVDial to check the connectivity status, and the output is as below: root@texe_hub:~# wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.



Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?

Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial

Comment: Also, during Modprobe, I have got the below error: [ 312.904695] usbserial_generic: probe of 1-1:1.0 failed with error -5.[ 312.911203] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.

[ 312.934684] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.

[ 312.954987] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.1: generic converter detected

[ 312.979489] usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0